# Embed a Collection of Forms : Add a Tag jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, symfony, symfony-2.2

I'm trying to reproduce the Symfony 2 Cookbook Tutorial [Add a new Tag](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html#allowing-new-tags-with-the-prototype)

I'm using exactly the same code like in the tutorial but I have some problems with the jQuery include.

new.html.twig  :

```
<form action="..." method="POST" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
    {# render the task's only field: description #}
    {{ form_row(form.description) }}

    <h3>Tags</h3>
    <ul class="tags" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.tags.vars.prototype)|e }}">
        {# iterate over each existing tag and render its only field: name #}
        {% for tag in form.tags %}
            <li>{{ form_row(tag.name) }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    <a href="#" class="add_tag_link">Add a tag</a>
    {{ form_rest(form) }}
    {# ... #}
</form>
```

This is how i include the jquery in the base.html.twig:
`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>`

Next Step:
Add a script tag somewhere on your page so you can start writing some JavaScript.

So I copy pasted this in the base.html.twig ,too.

```
// Get the ul that holds the collection of tags
var collectionHolder = $('ul.tags');

// setup an "add a tag" link
var $addTagLink = $('<a href="#" class="add_tag_link">Add a tag</a>');
var $newLinkLi = $('<li></li>').append($addTagLink);

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    // add the "add a tag" anchor and li to the tags ul
    collectionHolder.append($newLinkLi);

    // count the current form inputs we have (e.g. 2), use that as the new
    // index when inserting a new item (e.g. 2)
    collectionHolder.data('index', collectionHolder.find(':input').length);

    $addTagLink.on('click', function (e) {
        // prevent the link from creating a "#" on the URL
        e.preventDefault();

        // add a new tag form (see next code block)
        addTagForm(collectionHolder, $newLinkLi);
    });
});

function addTagForm(collectionHolder, $newLinkLi) {
    // Get the data-prototype explained earlier
    var prototype = collectionHolder.data('prototype');

    // get the new index
    var index = collectionHolder.data('index');

    // Replace '__name__' in the prototype's HTML to
    // instead be a number based on how many items we have
    var newForm = prototype.replace(/__name__/g, index);

    // increase the index with one for the next item
    collectionHolder.data('index', index + 1);

    // Display the form in the page in an li, before the "Add a tag" link li
    var $newFormLi = $('<li></li>').append(newForm);
    $newLinkLi.before($newFormLi);
}
```

At the end I wrote Add a tag after the  list.

But when I click on the Add a Tag Link, no new Tag input field appears.

Comment: If you mean when your click on the add tag link you added after your list it's normal. The click event is listenning on your `$addTagLink` object so it'll only work if you click on the add tag link in your list.

Comment: I made you a fiddle for example : http://jsfiddle.net/GXy6g/

Comment: hey thanks really much Coussinsky , but how comes that Symfony uses a $addTagLink variable  and how do i uses this variable?

Comment: The Tutorial says: "add a link to the bottom of the "tags" list via JavaScript" and i don't know what they mean with add a link via javascript

Comment: in the cookbook their addtaglink is automatic, it's added to the new line everytime you click on the same button see : http://jsfiddle.net/GXy6g/1/ so it depend how you want to implement it you can do both methods

Answer (score 0):

See browser debugger. Is there any errors?
Maybe you use old jquery version?
Make sure that jquery is enabled and support 'on' event (since 1.9 version).